# VScode Folder automatically closes when vscode get closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before:

[image: vscode after opening the folder]

After:

[image: folder closed automatically]

When i am doing quit(cmd+Q) and reopening it, it loads the previous folder which i am working at, but if i press the top left red button and reopen everything is gone, i have to reopen the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the corresponding settings in Window: Restore Window. Default is `all`

[image: setting]

If you prefer the settings.json

```json
"window.restoreWindows": "all"
```

Copied from vscode [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first
> time. This setting has no effect when the application is already
> running.
>
> - preserve: Always reopen all windows. If a folder or workspace is opened (e.g. from the command line) it opens as a new window unless it
>   was opened before. If files are opened they will open in one of the
>   restored windows.
> - all: Reopen all windows unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line).
> - folders: Reopen all windows that had folders or workspaces opened unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command
>   line).
> - one: Reopen the last active window unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line).
> - none: Never reopen a window. Unless a folder or workspace is opened (e.g. from the command line), an empty window will appear.

Comment: already tried, not working

Comment: check if the setting you've set is for `User` scope or for `Workspace` scope.
User scope will have a global effect, while `Workspace` will affect the current project/folder only

Comment: not working, i have settings for user scope

Comment: its working when i am quitting it using (cmd+Q), but when i close using the red button on top left, then everything is gone, i had to add the folder again.

Comment: do you have some kind of program that force quit others?

Comment: no i don't have any program.